# Is this expression for $x\pmod n$ interesting; nontrivial?

Tags: trigonometry, modular-arithmetic, uniform-convergence

For example, we would get several interesting results if we had a formula for $x\pmod n$ that was uniformly convergent, however, according to Wikipedia ([Floor and Ceiling Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)) these formulas do not exist because $x\pmod n$ is not continuous.  However, as I was playing with the graphs of different functions, I discovered that this one exactly replicates the mod function. $$\frac{n}{2}+\frac{n}{\pi}\arctan\left(\tan\left(\pi\left(\frac{x}{n}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)\right).$$ You can see this graph for yourself [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/j1ek3d1bo6).

So is an expression like this where the $\arctan$ and $\tan$ functions should cancel out useful?  If so, what are some other examples where this happens?

**Added**:  I realize now that $\arctan(\tan(x))\ne x$, but the general idea of my question still stands: is this function I have interesting?

Comment: That's pretty cool!

Comment: I'd be careful that you're not just trying to approximate modular arithmetic *by doing modular arithmetic*: note that although the $\arctan$ function is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and the identity $\tan (\arctan(x)) = x$ is always true, the converse is false! $\arctan(\tan(x)) = x \mod \pi$, which is not continuous! (note that $\tan$ is also not continuous...). So these formulas might just be a fancy way to obfuscate the $\mod n$ function.

Comment: $\arccos(\cos(x))$, $\arccos(\sin(x))$, $\arcsin(\cos(x))$, and $\arcsin(\sin(x))$ are interesting.

Comment: Any time you have a function with a multifunction inverse, you get weird things like that. We already know that $\sqrt{x^2}=\lvert x\rvert$.